# I changed some setting in the taskbar, removed a panel or something, and now my taskbar doesn't show applications I have open

Tags: lubuntu, taskbar

**Edit:  I figured it out!  Right click the taskbar, "Add widget" and select "task manager."**

The applications I have open don't appear in the taskbar.  My taskbar is just a big, empty bar at the bottom of the screen no matter how mamy applications are running.  When I minimize something, it just vanishes until I use alt+tab to reopen it.

I had right-clicked the taskbar and was messing around with cosmetic changed and apparently did something irreversible.  The problem started, I think, when I removed a panel, or maybe I removed a widget from a panel.  I don't even know what to Google to figure out how to resolve this (and Lord knows I've tried).  It was so easy to change that setting in the first place and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to undo it.

Comment: What release of Lubuntu are you using?   We cannot know if you're running legacy (LXDE) or modern (LXQt) without this detail, and thus cannot advise.   I'll provide the manual reference for the panel (latest release; ie. 19.10) - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html

Comment: Thank you!  I'll read through this.  For what it's worth, I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 but I don't know how to find what version of Lubuntu I'm using.

Comment: FYI:  19.04 was the answer I was after; meaning it's the 2019-April release (format is *year.month*).  Lubuntu is an official flavor of Ubuntu, thus it's possibly better to say Lubuntu (*which is on-topic for this, and Ubuntu sites*); as Ubuntu uses the GNOME desktop meaning a different GUI or graphical-user-interface; different to LXQt used by Lubuntu (thus different directions for many things).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was old but someone will benefit from it.
I also did this by right clicking on taskbar and then I clicked on remove taskbar. But I discovered how to bring it back. Just follow these steps:

1. Right click on taskbar and select "Manage Widgets". A window will open.
2. Click "+" button and search "task manager" select it and click add widget.
   That's all!